# Concatination + in javascript with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an issue with the variables + They both result me 310. But they both have to result me 13 because var1 = 3 and var2 = 10.

```
var var1 = document.getElementById("start").value;
var var2 = 10;
var3 = var1 + var2; 
alert(var3);
```

And Its Html:

```
<input type="text" id="start" value="3" />
```

Comment: Its HTML is : <input type="text" id="start" value="3" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have become strings. Convert to number

```
var var3 = Number(var1) + Number(var2);
```

Comment: Sorry. What is the issue for scroll bottom? Could u please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

just use `parseInt()` for the value you get from textbox

```
var var1 = document.getElementById("start").value;
var var2 = 10;
var3 = parseInt(var1) + var2; 
alert(var3);
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/amarsingh/458fmnpm/)

Comment: A second faster. Haha. I have the same answer https://jsfiddle.net/xkgb45b6/ Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

your trying to add two strings together. use the following to change them to numbers.

```
var var3  =  +var1 + +var2
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is this part,

```
document.getElementById("start").value
```

becaus it returns a string, as all input values are strings in HTML.

For using this value as a number, you could use various methods to convert a string to a number, like

- `parseInt(string, base)`, result is a integer number
- `parseFloat(string)`, result is a floating number
- `Number(string)`, using the number object
- `+string`, implicit casting to number with an unary plus symbol.
- and some others, like the minus symbol with calculation, like `string1 - string2` yields to `number - number`.